# Testing Proxy Rules using Powershell

Tags: powershell, proxy

Sometimes, our clients requests firewall rules for their web servers connect to a certain URL but it turns out that the URL's IP address is dynamic, so we resort to using the proxy. One way that we use to test the proxy rules is to pull up the web servers' browser e.g. IE then set it up to use our proxy server then hit the URL on the browser. Our clients have a lot of web servers that we host so we would like to automate the testing part. Any ideas on doing it using PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it does what you want. But the is code which I found some days ago:

```
$secPasswd=ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$myCreds=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "Domain\name",$secPasswd
$Site="http://www.google.com"
$Test=Invoke-WebRequest -URI $Site -Proxy 'http://ipadress:port' -ProxyCredential $mycreds
$Test.StatusDescription
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!